# Excel::Writer::XLSX adding format after writing to cell

Tags: perl

I am writing out a spreadsheet using the Excel::Writer::XLSX module and everything works fine.  I wanted to ask if it is possible to issue a 'set_column' with a particular format to change some columns that have already been written using another format.  The older format does not use the border attribute.  Does the new format using the add_column override the old format from the previous write?

I'm basically putting borders around certain columns using the add_column, but the add_column is not doing it.

```
my $fmt_border = $workbook->add_format( border => 1);
$worksheet->set_column( 'A:A', 40, $fmt_border );
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `set_column` instead of `add_column` in your question?

Comment: To quote [Excel::Write::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#set_column(-$first_col,-$last_col,-$width,-$format,-$hidden,-$level,-$collapsed-)): "This method can be used to change the default properties of a single column or a range of columns.". So I guess you would need to clear any possible formats that are already attached to the cells?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I meant to say set_column, not add_column.  I was confusing the add_format.  I think whatever format is in 'write' will take precendence over set_column.